# Why does JDK 1.8 install partially in two locations?

Tags: java, android-studio, java-8

**Windows 7, 64 bit.**

I was facing issues with Android Studio 2.1 and decided to install Java 1.8 in D:\Java because my C: is almost full. In the JDK installer dialog, I chose this location.

I was surprised to find that

D:\Java has

[image: D:\Java missing tools.jar]

I was surprised to find that part of the JDK is also installed here

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102 has

[image: surprised to find that part of the JDK is also installed here C:]

Now my Android Studio does not launch at all! I get this error

[image: tools.jar is not found in classpath]

I tried setting JAVA_HOME to D:\Java but that failed. I had to set it to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102 for Android Studio to launch. So what happens to the files in D:\Java?

Comment: You should un-check the option "Install Public JRE" when installing the JDK.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name should I uninstall and do a custom install to uncheck the option?

Comment: You set the location of the “public JRE” to `D:\Java` but kept the location for the JDK at its default. The correct approach is to disable the “public JRE” and alter the location of the JDK. Java 9 is supposed to get rid of this issue.

Comment: @Holger I uninstalled both. Is the public JRE needed for other programs to run? How should I install Java 8 now?

Comment: The JDK contains its own JRE, which you can use for running programs. The “public JRE” is needed for, e.g. the browser plugin. I use Java without it for years now…

Comment: @Holger tried your suggestion. it fails because in the install dialog, I uncheck the Public JRE option and the "Change" location button becomes disabled. I checked and Java is still installed in C:Program Files...

Comment: After unchecking the “public JRE”, you must select the JDK feature to change its target location. Otherwise, you changed the “public JRE” location, as you did before.

Comment: @Holger great! that worked - please put it as an answer and I will select it.

Answer (score 0):

The SDK installs both the SDK and the JRE, so the Classpath and path is set to the JRE you need to repoint it to the D:\java location

It also looks like it installed the tutorials and JavaFX to the C location

You can move the folders from C to D and repoint the JAVA_HOME path and the PATH variable. and it will still work, if you look at the other installations of Java, they can come in Zip files so you just move all the files from C: to D: and repoint the variables and it will work

Comment: I tried setting JAVA_HOME to D:\Java but that failed. I had to set it to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102 for Android Studio to launch. So what happens to the files in D:\Java? @TheresaForster The C location seems to have the actual tools.jar.

Comment: Copy C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\* to D:\Java then repoint to JAVA_HOME=D:\java  Path += D:\Java\bin

Comment: No, it is not necessary.Please see solution vy Holger.